# ACE editor count number of characters?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

This is how I am getting the total number of lines in ACE editor...

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(){
    var lines = editor.session.getLength();
    $('#lines').empty().append(lines);
});
```

This works fine, but how can I get the total characters also? I can't find any information on this in the API documentation.

Thanks.

**EDIT...**

This is how I ended up doing this... it also divides the output with a thousands separator.

```
var lines = setting.editor.getLength().toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
var chars = setting.editor.getValue().length.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
$('#lines').empty().append(lines);
$('#chars').empty().append(chars);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
console.log(editor.session.getValue().length);
```